# How to insert time 2009-09-22 18:09:37.881 in MYSQL My column type is DateTime

Tags: mysql

How to insert time `2009-09-22 18:09:37.881` in mysql. Actually I can insert and retrieve the time `2009-09-22 18:09:37` in mysql but whenever I am trying to insert `2009-09-22 18:09:37.881` data did not get inserted in database.

```
2009-09-22 18:09:37.881     ------->  YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:Sec.Ms
```

I have created a table using the below query

```
Create table XYZ(MyTime DateTime);
```

I tried the below query which worked fine

```
insert into XYZ(MyTime) values('2009-09-22 18:09:37');
```

But I tried with the below query which did not work fine (Data didnot get insert in database)

```
 insert into XYZ(MyTime) values('2009-09-22 18:11:38.881');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the issue resolved. The database was not allowing the insertion of time in millisecond. Please have a look at the lines, below:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTimeStamp(TimeData decimal(17,3));

INSERT INTO  MyTimeStamp(TimeData) values (20090922201843.426);

SELECT timestamp(TimeData) FROM MyTimeStamp;
```

### OutPut:

```
2009-09-22 20:018:43.426000
```

Comment: Great work, it saved my time as I am using mysql lower than 5.6.4

Answer (score 2):

The fractional second capability was finally added in MySQL 5.6.4. 
Link to documentaion: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html

Answer (score 1):

Having had a quick scan on the MySQL reference pages [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html), they seem to suggest that you cannot add milliseconds to a column of type datetime. The direct quote is

> "However, microseconds cannot be
>   stored into a column of any temporal
>   data type. Any microseconds part is
>   discarded."

This implies that you cannot use Timestamp either.

Are the miliseconds necessary? Could they be stored in a secondary column and then recombined with the basic datetime upon retrieval?

Answer (score 0):

All time types in MySQL have only a [precision of seconds](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html)

> [...] microseconds cannot be stored into a column of any temporal data type. Any microseconds part is discarded.

You'll need some workaround.

Comment: I created table using the command CREATE TABLE MyTimeZone (MyTime timestamp). Then I inserted timestamp using the following query insert into MyTimeZone(MyTime) values('2009-09-22 19:05:02.897');

Then I retrieved the data using the follwing command
Select * from MyTimeZone

I received the time zone as  2009-09-22 19:05:02 
I did not receive the exact time stamp that I have inserted. My time stamp includes milliseconds also

Comment: Timestamp also only has a precision of seconds.  5th paragraph here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: Actually I want to store millisecond also in table

Comment: @Evernoob: Great ... :( Now I've seen DATE columns which have a time, databases which don't support TIME at all ... and now that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
# PHP
$microtime = microtime(true);
$datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
?>
```

## MYSQL

- CREATE field col_datetime - DATETIME)
- CREATE field col_microtime - DECIMAL(15,4)

ADD:
INSERT INTO your_table (col_datetime,col_microtime) values ('$datetime','$microtime')

List new->old:
SELECT * FROM yout_table ORDER BY col_microtime DESC

List old->new:
SELECT * FROM yout_table ORDER BY col_microtime