# Time with frames in java

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, struts

I have to store time in form `hh:mm:ss:ff` i.e.,  hours, min, secs and frames where there are 25 frames in a second.

Which datatype is suitable or should I create seperate columns for hour, min, sec, frames?

Comment: What is this frames stuff?

Comment: frames is sub unit  of second where 25 frame = 1 sec

Comment: That doesn't make sense. A sub unit has to be a fraction of the super unit. In your case it could make sense to make seconds a sub unit of frame. After all, go with Rene's answer.

Comment: @BetaRide frames is smaller unit than second.This form of time  is  used for videos

Answer (score 1):

Is 1 frame always 25 seconds and the other way around?
If so, just store it as either seconds OR frames as an `Integer` and calculate the rest.

Comment: I believe to save it as string i.e hh:mm:ss:ff  and use  a function to convertit  to time where ever needed.

Comment: @user2229994 Why? What's the difference if you convert it to, or from, a string? Storing as a number also allows trivial math without having to convert first.

Comment: @user2229994 Saving `1:10:30:25` as a `String` is `10 Bytes`. Saving it as an `Unsigned Integer` instead you can get up to  4,294,967,295 seconds (136 years) with just `4 Bytes` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my eyes, as far as concerned to way of storing, it doesn't matter. Why?:

Well, your target format contains a non standard part of time, so you have to convert it somewhere in your code. That fact opens -at least- two ways:

- In case you want to use the standard database format, you uses
  milliseconds for the number of 'frames'. Due to the fact that 25
  frames -by the way reminds me on framerate of a video- are 1 second,
  so are 40 milliseconds one frame.

or

- In case you want to use the standard database format, you can store the time without unit `frame` in standard format and add an additional column in your database table. In that do your store the number of frames. After reading the stored data, you have to put both columns together.

I think the last idea is a good compromise between your options, whose you menthioned in your question.

Comment: Thanks,i think using using your  first option is good. Which data type is to be used to store time(hh:mm:ss:mmmm) only in java and database

Comment: For mySQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459909/how-to-insert-time-2009-09-22-180937-881-in-mysql-my-column-type-is-datetime. As concerned of the date part (year, month, day) use alsways the same date. Is it to much work, take a look at my second idea. In Java use 'java.util.Date'.