# Get created_at with millisecond precision from database in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.1. I want to get milliseconds precision for created_at that I get from the database.

I have tried the solution given for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227069/laravel-timestamps-to-show-milliseconds). But there isn't any change. Also I tried raw query. Still I get only up to seconds. Is there any way to get millisecond precision?

Comment: You want to insert in to database or use for naming convention you can try Something like this " Carbon\Carbon::now()->timestamp"

Comment: i got data like  "created_at": "2017-02-07 19:10:44"   "updated_at": "2017-02-07 19:10:44" instead of "created_at": "2017-02-07 19:10:44.976"
    +"updated_at": "2017-02-07 19:10:44.976"

Comment: If you want time stamp then this can help you I am using it in laravel you have to try once

Comment: the thing is i wants it in millisecond precision in above format

Comment: Try this might can help you "$time    = microtime(true);
 $mSecs   =  $time - floor($time);
 $mSecs   =  substr($mSecs,1);
 echo Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y H:i:s').$mSecs;
"

Comment: I have to get the exact time that stored in my db. When i retrieve it from db, i got data after truncating the milliseconds. If i convert that data, i didn't get the milliseconds precision.What i get is some zero in that precision.Hope you get what i meant.

Comment: To store millisecond in database you need some different column format: Look this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299149/timestamp-with-a-millisecond-precision-how-to-save-them-in-mysql

Comment: And this is also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459909/how-to-insert-time-2009-09-22-180937-881-in-mysql-my-column-type-is-datetime

Answer (score -2):

It may be a problem about your column type. Assuming you are using MySQL, you should manually add (or modify) a column with type `TIMESTAMP(3)` on your table:

```
\DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `my_table` ADD COLUMN my_col TIMESTAMP(3) NULL");
```

More information here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html

Comment: I have tried many solution to insert created_at with millisecond precision. But what i get is only up to seconds. Then i manually edit my database and write trigger to update the column. But the problem arises when i try to retrieve it from db.

Comment: You have a problem on insert/get, but did you modify the **schema** of your table? (modify the column) What's the type of the column?

Comment: yup. timestamp(3)

Comment: At inserting, make sure your eloquent model doesn't have the column name added to protected $dates.